# MDIChild Form always behind ScrollBox

Tags: delphi, mdichild, delphi-10.3-rio, tscrollbox

Based in [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57749927/9708179) my working code, now i need of a `ScrollBox` component and a `Image` component inside he. Eg:

[image]

The problem now is the `ScrollBox`. The MDIChild Form always stays behind, you can test, changing `ScrollBox` **Align** (*None*/*Client*) property.

Then what is need to MDIChild Form stay above of `ScrollBox`?

Comment: What do you want to do? Even if an mdi child would come in front of the scrollbox, it wouldn't be a child of the scrollbox and so the scrollbox wouldn't scroll the children.

Comment: Is it what you want, scroll mdi children into view when they are moved to sides?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MDI client window that hosts the MDI child forms is the bottom most window of the MDIForm's content. You can't make MDI child forms appear on top of anything else, because literally everything else placed on the MDIForm is on top of the MDI client window and thus on top of the child forms.